# How can I define the pod's name of replicas using deployment?

Tags: kubernetes

I am doing a deployment with kubernetes using the following template:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ter-deployment
  labels:
    app: ter
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: ter
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: ter
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: ter
        image: ter:0.0.1
        ports:
        - containerPort: 4000
        env:
        - name: MONGO_URI
          valueFrom:
            secretKeyRef:
              name: mongo-uri
              key: mongo-uri
        - name: NODE_ENV
          value: prod
        - name: LOGS_PATH
          value: logs
```

The problem with this is that when I apply this, kubernetes creates one pod with the following name:

ter-xxxxxx

How can I set that xxxx?

Thanks

Comment: You can't. What problem are you trying to solve? Usually _labels_ is a good thing to use.

Comment: I am trying to ensure a access outside of cluster with a client.

Comment: You don't need the Pod-name for that. Create a Service, and perhaps an Ingress resource.

Comment: To add details about Jonas's answer https://kubernetes.io/docs/tutorials/kubernetes-basics/expose/expose-intro/ and https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Thanks both for the response.